# Import text Files to excel workbook using VB.Net

Tags: excel, vb.net

I am trying to add Some text files to Excel workbook using vb.net.I want to add 6 text files in my resources folder as templates for the 6 sheets i want to create.I am able to create separate workbooks for each text file but have trouble putting together a code to add all text files into a single work book.I am copying the code that i have right now.How can i do this?

```
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application = New Excel.Application With {.Visible =True}
    Dim XlDesTemplateBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlDesTemplateSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim xlDesTemplateSheet1 As Excel.Worksheet
    XlDesTemplateBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add()
    xlDesTemplateSheet1 = XlDesTemplateBook.Worksheets.Add("File Path1")
    xlDesTemplateSheet1 = XlDesTemplateBook.Worksheets.Add("File Path2")
```

I am getting this error when i tries to run the code.

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC'

Comment: Ho can i improve my question,any suggestion?.As soon as i put a question in it is getting downvoted.. My bad...

Comment: "How can i improve my question,any suggestion?" - Show us that you have performed some research on the subject.  The minimal research should include reading the documentation for [Sheets.Add Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/sheets-add-method-excel).  Excel's macro recorder is a great tool to discover a workable syntax as well. Now it is forgivable, to try the `Add` method on the `Worksheets` object as it is a `Sheets` object.  However  it will not work;  you must use the `Workbook.Sheets` object's `Add` method instead with the proper syntax.

Answer (score 0):

This worked fine for me.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

Public Class Form1
    Dim objexcel As New Excel.Application
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim Paths() As String = Directory.GetFiles("C:\your_path_here\", "*.txt")
        For Each Path As String In Paths
            File.AppendAllText("C:\your_path_here\TextFileToWriteTo.txt", File.ReadAllText(Path), Encoding.Default) 'The text file will be created if it does not already exist  
        Next
        Dim objexcel As New Excel.Application
        objexcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        objexcel.Visible = True
        objexcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\your_path_here\TextFileToWriteTo.txt",,,,,,,,,,,,,,)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I will try it tomorrow.Thanks

Comment: its adding only three files, can you explain how your code is suppose to work.

Comment: I simplified my original post and re-posted.  Try that.  That will definitely work for you.  Please up-vote if you find it helpful.  Thanks.